# How can I serve a React app from Flask backend

Tags: flask, configuration, environment-variables, create-react-app, static-files

I have a frontend app written in React (plain [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/) project) that uses a backend written in Python using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/).

I'd like to set up the project in the following way:

- In production: The backend serves the optimized frontend build on path `/`. The endpoints used by the frontend are registered on other paths on the same server.
- In development I run the apps separately (using `npm run start` and `flask --app=app.py run`) in order to take advantage of the tooling provided by CRA. This means that the frontend and backend run on different ports on localhost, so the frontend must be told where the backend is. So the backend does *not* serve the frontend in dev.

The way I'm thinking to achieve this is using environment variables:

- Frontend: `BACKEND_URL_BASE` specifies the URL base of the backend. It's empty in production and non-empty in dev.
- Backend: `FRONTEND_PATH` specifies the location of the static files produced by `npm run build`.

Comment: _"the frontend must be told where the backend is"_ - you're not really taking advantage of the tooling provided by CRA that way. Use the [_proxy_](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/), to get consistency between the dev and prod environments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Right that seems like a simpler solution for this setup. I guess the `BACKEND_URL_BASE` is only needed if you *don't* serve the frontend from the backend in prod. I might edit that in the answer later, though leaving it could be useful for related problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Frontend

Env vars prefixed by `REACT_APP_` are [automatically exposed](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) to the application on the `process.env` object. For example, `REACT_APP_MYVAR` is avaliable as `process.env.REACT_APP_MYVAR`. It's intentionally impossible (for security reasons) to pass variables without this prefix.

As the build produces static files, these values cannot be set at startup unless the backend also builds the frontend on startup. While it could definitely do that, there's no need in this setup because the value is empty in the production build (and in development there's no distinction between build and startup).

(Side note: An alternative to building the frontend on the backend is also to let the Flask app use `render_template` to serve a parameterized `index.html` file.)

Assuming that the API endpoints are grouped under the context path `/api`, the build variable `REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL_BASE` is then consumed in the app like so:

```js
// Default to path '/api' relative to the current URL root.
export const BACKEND_URL_BASE = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL_BASE || `${window.location.origin}/api`;
```

Note that defaulting to `/api` is insufficient if you intend to use the variable to [construct a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object (i.e. `` new URL(`${BACKEND_URL_BASE}/my_endpoint`) `` as the full address must be explicitly specified.

The value of `REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL_BASE` can be set directly in `package.json` for convenience:

```json
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "start": "REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL_BASE='http://localhost:5000/api' react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
    },
```

where `http://localhost:5000` is the address of the development Flask app. The value is left empty when building for production to get the default behavior.

## Backend

*Reading config*

Flask applications are initialized using the [`Flask(...)`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=static#application-object) function:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, ...)
...
```

Just like the React variables have a particular prefix, Flask variables are prefixed with `FLASK_` and are loaded into `app.config` using the method `app.config.from_prefixed_env()` ([docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/config/)). While we could read `FRONTEND_PATH` using standard Python methods (`os.environ`), this method generally integrates better with Flask. The values are accessed using `app.config.get(<name>, <default>)`, where `<name>` is the variable name without the `FLASK_` prefix and `<default>` is the default value if `FLASK_<name>` was not provided:

```py
app.config.from_prefixed_env()
app.config.get('FRONTEND_PATH', '../frontend/build')
```

This example reads `FLASK_FRONTEND_PATH` from the environment, falling back to `../frontend/build` (which is the correct path in development mode) if no value was found.

*Static file handler*

By default, Flask automatically sets up a route for serving static files from the directory `./static` on the root URL path (`/`). The behavior is configured using the following named parameters of `Flask(...)`:

- `static_folder` (default: `'static'`): The handler is set up unless this is `None`.
- `static_url_path` (default: `None`): Determines on which URL base path to register the handler. The value `None` [means](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2.2.2/src/flask/scaffold.py#L282) "the basename of `static_folder`".

The handler is registered in the initial `Flask(...)` call which creates the `app` object. But the value of the frontend path is read using `app.config`, so we got ourselves a circular dependency.

Fortunately, only the *presence* of an initial value of `static_folder` determines whether the handler should be registered or not - the actual value doesn't matter initially. In particular:

- Flask [doesn't check](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2.2.2/src/flask/app.py#L699) whether the folder exist. If it doesn't, then the handler will just fail to serve any requests.
- The value of the [parameter is mutable](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2.2.2/src/flask/scaffold.py#L256) via `app.static_folder`. Changes are immediately reflected in the request handler.

In other words, we just need to provide *some* non-`None` value of `static_folder` in the initial call to `Flask(...)` but are free to assign a new value to `app.static_folder` once the actual value has been loaded from config.

It we worry that Flask could serve requests from unintended places in the time between the handler is created and the folder is changed, we could provide an invalid dummy path as the initial value. I believe that `</>` is an invalid path on all platforms. In reality I don't think Flask actually starts listening for requests until all setup is completed, and the default value of `static` is probably fine. But I like to be explicit and limit reliance on default values.

The correct value of `static_url_path` [must be provided up front](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2.2.2/src/flask/app.py#L710), but that's fine as we don't want that to be configurable anyway.

Combining the pieces we arrive at the solution:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='</>', static_url_path='')
app.config.from_prefixed_env()
app.static_folder = app.config.get('FRONTEND_PATH', '../frontend/build')
```

## Bonus: Docker

The following Dockerfile builds the frontend and an image containing the backend with the expected production configuration to be served by a [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/index.html) WSGI server:

```
ARG gunicorn_version=20.0

FROM node:hydrogen-buster-slim AS frontend
WORKDIR /build
COPY ./frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./frontend .
RUN npm run build

FROM python:3-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./backend/requirements.txt .
ARG gunicorn_version
RUN pip install \
    --disable-pip-version-check \
    --no-cache-dir \
    --root-user-action=ignore \
    -r requirements.txt \
    gunicorn~=${gunicorn_version}
COPY ./backend/*.py ./
COPY --from=frontend /build/build ./frontend
ENV FLASK_FRONTEND_PATH='./frontend'
#ENTRYPOINT ["flask", "--app=./app.py", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8080"]
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "--bind=0.0.0.0:8080", "app:app"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

The image is built using `docker build -t <tag>` from the project root, where `<tag>` is the image tag to use for the image, the frontend source is assumed to be located in folder `./frontend` and backend is in `./backend`.

Run the image using `docker run -p <port>:8080 <tag>` to run a container from the image locally on port `<port>`.

See the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/) for more information.